# Android Java - OnCreate executes, but fails to create tables?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, oncreate

I'm working on my first Android project (full disclosure, this is a school project). I must confess I'm finding it to be much more convoluted than I expected. Anyway, here's my issue.

I've created a DBHelper class:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "asteroids.sqlite";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public DBHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        System.out.println("DB HELPER ON CREATE FUNCTION HERE!!!!");
        db.beginTransaction();
        resetAsteroidsTable(db);
        // Call functions to create each table.
        // Create/Reset BGObject Table
        resetBGObjectsTable(db);
        // GameLevels
        resetGameLevelsTable(db);
        // Level Objects
        resetLevelObjectsTable(db);
        // Level Asteroids
        resetLevelAsteroidsTable(db);
        // Main Bodies
        resetMainBodiesTable(db);
        // Cannons
        resetCannonsTable(db);
        // Extra Parts
        resetExtraPartsTable(db);
        // Engines
        resetEnginesTable(db);
        // Power Cores
        resetPowerCoresTable(db);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)       {
        return;
    }
```

The functions getting called to create individual tables are of this format:

```
   public void resetAsteroidsTable(SQLiteDatabase db)


   {
        // Create/Reset Asteroids Table
        final String SQL =
                "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ASTEROIDS; " +

                        "CREATE TABLE ASTEROIDS " +
                        "(" +
                        "        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        "        IMAGEPATH TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        "        IMAGEWIDTH INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                        "        IMAGEHEIGHT INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                        "        ASTYPE TEXT NOT NULL " +
                        ");";
        System.out.println("Create the ASTEROIDS database!");
        System.out.println(SQL);
        db.execSQL(SQL);
```

I've checked the create table SQL statements manually and they do work.

However, when I call this function also found in DBHelper to insert data into one of the tables.

```
public boolean executeSqlStatement(String SQLStatement)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    db.execSQL(SQLStatement);
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
    return true;
}
```

I get the error:

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: ASTEROIDS (code 1):
```

I'm confused because I know that onCreate is getting called because I see my print statements in logcat. I'm clearing the app data each time I run my test that is doing this operation, and I do have access to the database dump that I'm getting using the humpty script. The database schema shows only a table called android_metadata which is empty.I've been looking online for hours, I'd really appreciate any pointers here.

Comment: As far as I know, not the same. Here I am actually getting into the onCreate function, no errors are thrown during oncreate process. Table still doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exeqSQL()` executes just one SQL statement. You need to split your SQL to individual calls, one for `DROP TABLE` and another for `CREATE TABLE`. Note that `onCreate()` is only invoked when the database file didn't exist so the `DROP TABLE` is really not needed.

Another issue is that `SQLiteOpenHelper` lifecycle methods such as `onCreate()` are invoked inside an transaction. You should not start a nested transaction yourself. SQLite itself does not support nested transactions, and Android's SQLite wrapper only adds partial support for transaction nesting.

Comment: Thanks, I went ahead and removed the transaction stuff from onCreate, the issue remains. As a side note, when do I need to use the transaction functions? only with raw sql?

Comment: There is another issue with trying to execute more than one SQL statement with `execSQL()`. Updated the answer.

Comment: thanks! That gave me the breakthrough I needed. I was only executing the drop table statements. Thus rendering an empty database.